# Toolbar con degradado alfa en Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Como se puede aplicar un degradado a la `Toolbar` pero solo cuando este extendido si pertenece dentro de un `CollapsingToolbarLayout`.

Es decir tengo una `Toolbar` que debajo de ella se visualiza una imagen, que se expande hacia la `Statusbar` y quiero resaltar los controles que se muestran encima de la imágen, la guia de [estilo de Material Design de Google](https://material.io/guidelines/style/imagery.html#imagery-principles) dice que se debe usar un degradado, oscuro a transparente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo he solucionado sobreponiendo el degradado encima de la imagen usando un `RelativeLayout`

**Antes**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Despues**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap"
        app:titleEnabled="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@drawable/about_background_header"
                android:contentDescription="@string/desc_empty"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/scrim_top_linear" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Recurso para el degradado `scrim_top_linear.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
    <gradient
        android:type="linear"
        android:centerX="40%"
        android:startColor="#99000000"
        android:centerColor="#00474747"
        android:endColor="#00000000"
        android:angle="270"/>
</shape>
```